# Why we need Spotinst function when we already have Azure function, AWS Lambda, Google cloud function

Tags: aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions, azure-functions

We already have Azure function in Microsoft Azure, AWS Lambda in AWS, Google Cloud Function in Google.

Then What are reasons do we need to use Spotinst function?

Wil Spotinst function replicated and running on all Cloud Providers such as Azure, AWS, Google and all regions at the same time when we choose all Cloud Providers and regions.

Which Cloud Providers will have to pay for running a Spotinst function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on [Spotinst](https://spotinst.com/products/elastigroup-3/), but I had a chance to chat with them at ServerlessConf NYC. It's my understanding that their value-prop is to save you money on cloud *infrastructure*. That's things like VMs.

You specifically mentioned Azure Functions, AWS Lambda, and Google Cloud Functions. Those are *Serverless/FaaS* services, which means that you as the developer don't need to think about infrastructure or VMs at all, and the consumption-based prices are already dirt-cheap. Serverless tech has it's limitations, however, which means they're not appropriate for all use-cases (for example, if you need to execute long-running code, or install special software on the VM instance that your code depends on).

In that light, Spotinst makes more sense for non-Serverless applications which need to run on cloud VMs.